# C++ closure capture variable

Tags: c++, closures

In the Cow() function. I'm trying to capture the variable weight to the closure. But it doesn't work correctly. Variable weight is not captured to the closure. When I was trying to run getWeight() function. It returned an uninitialized value. Also setWeight() does not work.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Mammal {
  std::function<void()> speak;
  std::function<int()> getWeight;
  std::function<void(int)> setWeight;
};

Mammal *Cow() {
    int weight = 100;

    auto *m = new Mammal();
    m->speak = []() { puts("momo~~ momo~~"); };
    m->getWeight = [&]() { return weight; };;
    m->setWeight = [&](int w) { weight = w; };

    return m;
}

int main() {
    Mammal *c = Cow();
    std::cout << "Cow Weight: " << c->getWeight() << '\n';

    c->setWeight(200);
    std::cout << "Cow New Weight: " << c->getWeight() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Where do you want that weight to live?

Comment: According to your description, `weight` should be class member variable instead of local variable. And `Mammal *Cow()` seems not a good way to create a `Mammal`. A class should be enough for this case without any `std::function`

Comment: @chris I want to weight have the lifetime captured in the mammal object.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes. I won't do this in real engineering project. I demonstrate this, just want to know how closure work with oop Polymorphism.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by capturing a lifetime. Currently, `weight` goes out of scope when the function call ends and that memory is reused for other stack purposes. You're going to have to pick somewhere that can outlive the function call, whether that be the free store, the closure object, or each class object (in which case make it an ordinary data member).

Comment: @chris Yes. But I'm using closure. By definition, closure will package the variables from enclosing function into itself, right? I have tried allocating weight on the heap. `int *weight = new int(100);` So the weight variable won't have lifetime issue. But still it does not work.

Comment: @chris Actually, it works when I do it like this. `int *weight = new int(100);`
`m->setWeight = [weight](int w) { *weight = w; };`

Comment: You need to klnow the [scope of a variable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141133/what-is-meant-by-scope-of-a-variable) before more backfires. What new does is create an variable in the heap and you never delete it.

Comment: The closure stores the variable however you tell it to. `[&]` captures a reference to things you use (pointer or not). If those things are out of scope, it's a dangling reference. That won't provide any place to store the actual weight, only a reference to it. Imagine `[&]` as `struct closure { int& weight;  ... };` for the first one and `struct closure { int*& weight; ... };` for the pointer.

Comment: @LouisGo I just didn't show the memory release code here. But thanks, I think I understood it now.

Comment: @chris That's right. I think I have got it. Thanks very much!